# how can i solve session_register error?

Tags: php, session

I have read the answers from other similar topics, but I'm not sure they work in my case.

I get a `session_register()` error, because it is not compatible with my PHP version.
To solve the problem, I replaced the function call `session_register('foo')` with

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = $foo;
```

However, I have a similar situation in my code:

```
$ _SESSION ['abilita_macro_categoria'] = $ abilita_macro_categoria;
session_register ('abilita_macro_categoria');
```

How do I solve that? Do I just delete the `session_register()` function?

Comment: `session_register()` is a way old way of doing something Really Insecure and dangerous. Definitely remove all of them.

Comment: Replace `session_register ('abilita_macro_categoria');` with `$_SESSION ['abilita_macro_categoria'] = $abilita_macro_categoria;` and watch out for those spaces between the `$` and the name

Comment: Of course you only require it once

Comment: Then just delete the unnecessary and dangerous `session_register ('abilita_macro_categoria');`

Comment: oh ok thank, i try this solution! i was not sure if deleting the session_register was ok, thanks

Comment: Its more than ok, its imperative

Comment: in situation like this

<code> if(isset($_GET['sezione'])){$_SESSION['sezione']=$_GET['sezione']; session_register('sezione');} </code>
i do the same thing?

Comment: Just delete the `session_register('sezione');` in that case

Comment: To clarify things: `session_register()` is how you would handle sessions in PHP/4.0.0, what means somewhere around years 2000 and 2001. If your code is really from that age you'll possibly have bigger problems.